# How to move folder from one place to another in SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

The following I have

> ProjectA ->
>        trunk
>        tags
>
> ProjectB ->
>        Trunk
>        Tags

How can I move all ProjectB stuff to ProjectA, keeping history. consider ProjectA would be empty. I'm using TortoiseSVn.Any help is appereciated as I don't want to mess things up.

Thanks

Timothy

Comment: you want to copy or just rename?

Comment: Well I want to rename, but either way I will get rid of ProjectB folder

Comment: If ProjectA is empty, just delete it and rename ProjectB.

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on a folder in your repository and choose `TortoiseSVN | Repo-browser`.  That will bring up a nice windows-explorer-like window in which you can rename folders, move them around, etc. via drag-and-drop and the right-click context menu.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both projects reside in the same repository:

check out a working copy of both projects. Since you're using TortoiseSVN, [right-drag](http://tortoisesvn.net/mostforgottenfeature.html) the folders and files from ProjectB to ProjectA and then select "SVN Move files to here" from the context menu.

However if the projects are in separate repositories, you have to use the svnadmin tool which comes with the command line client of Subversion.